# Weird characters using jquery prettyphoto plugin

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I'm using the prettyPhoto plugin and everything is OK except for two issues:

The box displays a weird character in the top and the title even when I set the option to hide it. This is my relevant code:

HTML:

```
  <a id="linkGraph" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" href="graph.php?iframe=true" title="Gráfica">Iframe</a>
  <a id="linkGraph" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" href="graph.php?iframe=true" title="Gráfica">Iframe</a>
  <a id="linkGraph" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" href="graph.php?iframe=true" title="Gráfica">Iframe</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    animation_speed: 'slow',
      social_tools: false,
      theme: 'facebook', /* pp_default / light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square / facebook */
      show_title: false
    });
```

But the result is:

[image: Result's code]

Why appear the items that I marked in red circles? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue =[

Answer (score 0):

try to use this :

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getting-strange-characters-using-ajax

---

Change the Header Type.
For PHP to serve UTF-8,

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: But I'm not using AJAX, it's an IFRAME.

Comment: no problem, try to change <html> or <iframe> tag with UTF specific type.